# I can't write a built-in bot

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I am writing a built-in bot on the **C#** and such a problem has arisen. I don't understand how to make the user enter a query when entering the bot's username, and the bot outputs the results. I don't understand at all where to insert a query into the code and bind the results to it.

Code:

```
private async static void BotOnInlineQuery(object sender, InlineQueryEventArgs e)
{
    InlineQueryResultBase[] results = new[]
    {
            new InlineQueryResultGif(e.InlineQuery.Id, "https://sticker-collection.com/Peepo_Pepe", "https://na-dache.pro/uploads/posts/2021-05/1620620302_8-p-domik-v-gorakh-foto-10.jpg")
        };

    await client.AnswerInlineQueryAsync(e.InlineQuery.Id,
        results,
        nextOffset: "a",
        isPersonal: true,
}
```